# Why does this program which finds the smallest triangle number with >500 factors crash?

Tags: c++, factorization

I have written the program below to solve Project Euler 12, which involves finding the smallest triangle number with over 500 factors.

I don't think there are major errors. I suspect memory optimization may be an issue. That being said, however, I need the unsigned long long int for the large triangle number that will eventually be the answer. I start my natural number sequence at triangleNumbers[0]=10,000,000,000. I know 9,000,000,000 has roughly 300 factors, so 10,000,000,000 was a "best guess."
That being said, however, I assume that 10,000,000,000 is the "first natural number" and continue adding subsequent natural numbers to get the "second" natural number and beyond (so triangleNumbers[1]=10,000,000,000 + 2, triangleNumbers[2]=10,000,000,000 +3, and so forth).

Any suggestions and tips would be appreciated. Thank you for helping a beginner improve.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

bool keepRunning=true;

unsigned long long int naturalNumberCount=0;
unsigned long long int j=4;
unsigned long long int sum=0;

vector <unsigned long long int> triangleNumbers(0);

unsigned long long int totalFactors=0;
unsigned long long int trialDivisors=1;

unsigned long long int storer=0;

int main()
{
    triangleNumbers[0]=10000000000;
    triangleNumbers[1]=10000000002;
    triangleNumbers[2]=10000000005;
    triangleNumbers[3]=10000000009;
    triangleNumbers[4]=10000000014;
    //listed first few prime numbers above. j is set at 4 for this reason

    naturalNumberCount=5;
    //10000000014 is the 5th triangle number, and 5 is the 5th natural num
    //need this for recursive relation
    //5th triangle number = 4th triangle num + 5 (num + naturalNumberCount

    while(keepRunning)
    {
        for(trialDivisors;trialDivisors<=(unsigned long long int)(sqrt(triangleNumbers[j]));trialDivisors++)
        {
            if(triangleNumbers[j]%trialDivisors==0)
            {
                totalFactors++;
                if(totalFactors>499)//499 because the number itself will be a divisor of itself, so no need to check
                {
                    keepRunning=false;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    keepRunning=true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                keepRunning=true;
            }
        }
        //need the below to generate and store the next triangle number (as next element of array)

        naturalNumberCount++;//for recursive relation
        storer=triangleNumbers[j];//store the (j+1)'th triangle number, since we are changing j itself
        j++;//raise j, we gonna add the next value
        triangleNumbers[j]=(storer+naturalNumberCount);//the new value (last triangle number + current natural)
        totalFactors=0;//reset total factors to preclude any carry-over
    }


    cout<<triangleNumbers[j]<<flush;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So when you debugged it, where did you find that it crashed?

Comment: Here is a hint -- you have a vector that is empty and you're trying to access items in it.

Comment: And incrementing  j will make vector goes oit of bound anyways ....

Comment: *I don't think there are major errors* -- There are serious errors, right on the first line of `main`.  Please take a look at my answer.

Comment: Also, `sqrt(triangleNumbers[j])` -- this is not guaranteed to give you the correct or expected integer, once it is casted.  It is a floating point function, and once you enter the floating point realm, you are risking a truncation / round-off issue.

Comment: Those numbers aren't triangle numbers. I would consider that a major error. You also don't need to store more than one of them.

Comment: Also, 10000000000 has only 121 divisors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TL;DR`

```
#include <vector>

std::vector <unsigned long long int> triangleNumbers(0);

int main()
{
    triangleNumbers[0]=10000000000;
}
```

You have an empty vector, and the very first line in `main` leads to undefined behavior since you're trying to access item `0` (there is no such item).

[Live Example using operator [ ]](http://ideone.com/FgOweQ)

[Live Example showing what vector::at() does](http://ideone.com/ZCgwoD)

Note the second link demonstrates that you are accessing an element out of bounds by using `at()` instead of `[ ]` to access the first item.

To add items to a `std::vector`, use one of the methods designed to do this, namely `vector::push_back()`, `vector::insert()`, `vector::emplace_back()`, `vector::resize()`, or construct the `std::vector` with the requisite number of entries.

The easiest out of all of these options would be to construct the vector using the initializer list:

`std::vector<unsigned long long int> triangleNumbers = 
        {10000000000, 10000000002, 10000000005, 10000000009, 10000000014};`

[std::vector reference](http://ideone.com/FgOweQ)

Once you properly set up the vector, then you need to look at the rest of your code, to see where you may be accessing an out-of-bounds index.  Especially take a look at `j` in your loop, and how you're using it as an index.  The `vector::at()` function will tell you immediately if `j` goes out of bounds.

---

EDIT:  If you really wanted a syntax that would simulate an "auto-expanded" array, the closest you can come to this would be to use a `std::unordered_map<int, unsigned long long>` as seen by [this example](http://ideone.com/CDGkoH).

Possibly the `map` solution would be a drop-in replacement -- you would have to test it.

Comment: Interesting. I wrongly believed that a vector simply "expands" dynamically, as needed. Guess I need to use push-back.

Comment: You can initialize the `vector` with the first 5 items, as my answer shows.  However, you definitely need to use `push_back` or other "expansion" function if you're going to add items later on.

Comment: @Shehryar I updated my answer to show that a close equivalent to a simulation of an auto-expanded vector would be to use a map of some type.